# Servlet filter isn't being invoked on .html file of GWT module

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, servlets, servlet-filters

Perhaps I'm just missing some fundamental piece of knowledge but I can't figure out why servlet filter doesn't catch GET request on .html file of main GWT module.

My filter is defined in web.xml as

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>GaeAuthFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.test.GaeAuthFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>GaeAuthFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

When I launch the app in development mode it opens http://127.0.0.1:8888/AdminPanel.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 in the browser but nothing get caught in the filter :(

The reason I need this is that I don't want my authentication fail on RequestFactory ajax call since it looks ugly because it loads html first and then redirects to Google Accounts login page. I'd like to catch unauthenticated user at the moment of accessing html page so browser doesn't even load protected area of the web-site.

As alternative I tried to use "security-constraint" section of web.xml but it also ignores calls to .html file.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't looked in to why yet, but when I ran across this (while in a hurry), what worked was to remove `index.html` and make my `<welcome-file>` a .jsp

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dave. Your solution works for me. Even though @thomas was right about reasons why filter is not being invoked it's not working for me because GAE can't serve given static file.

Comment: Just wondering here... Anyone knows if, handling static files outside the servlet container, it's an Appengine characteristic or any java Servlet would behave like this?

Answer (score 8):

From [the AppEngine documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Servlets_and_URL_Paths):

> **Note:** Static files, files that are served verbatim to users such as images, CSS or JavaScript, are handled separately from paths mentioned in the deployment descriptor. A request for a URL path that matches a path to a file in the WAR that's considered a static file will serve the file, regardless of servlet and filter mappings in the deployment descriptor. You can exclude files from those treated as static files using the [appengine-web.xml](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html) file.

I don't do AppEngine, but I guess adding an `<exclude>` for the files you want the filter to apply to will do (the files will then be served by the *default servlet*; I guess that they'll be billed differently as a consequence)

Comment: You were right. Specifying target .html file in **static-files/exclude** of **appengine-web.xml** helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oops, let me actually take my words back. After some testing it turned out GAE can't serve the html. It says `WARNING: Can not serve /AdminPanel.html directly.  You need to include it in <static-files> in your appengine-web.xml.`